# How to create a stacked line plot

Tags: r, charts, diagram

There are multiple solutions to create a stacked bar plot in R, but how to draw a stacked line plot?

[image]

Comment: Many users seem to find this question while searching for a stacked bar plot. Look here: http://www.statmethods.net/graphs/bar.html

Answer (score 27):

A stacked line plot can be created with the `ggplot2` package.

Some example data:

```
set.seed(11)
df <- data.frame(a = rlnorm(30), b = 1:10, c = rep(LETTERS[1:3], each = 10))
```

The function for this kind of plot is `geom_area`:

```
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(df, aes(x = b, y = a, fill = c)) + geom_area(position = 'stack')
```

[image]

Answer (score 4):

Given that the diagram data is available as data frame with "lines" in columns and the Y-values in rows and given that the row.names are the X-values, this script creates stacked line charts using the polygon function.

```
stackplot = function(data, ylim=NA, main=NA, colors=NA, xlab=NA, ylab=NA) {
  # stacked line plot
  if (is.na(ylim)) {
    ylim=c(0, max(rowSums(data, na.rm=T)))
  }
  if (is.na(colors)) {
    colors = c("green","red","lightgray","blue","orange","purple", "yellow")
  }
  xval = as.numeric(row.names(data))
  summary = rep(0, nrow(data))
  recent = summary

  # Create empty plot
  plot(c(-100), c(-100), xlim=c(min(xval, na.rm=T), max(xval, na.rm=T)), ylim=ylim, main=main, xlab=xlab, ylab=ylab)

  # One polygon per column
  cols = names(data)
  for (c in 1:length(cols)) {
    current = data[[cols[[c]]]]
    summary = summary + current
    polygon(
      x=c(xval, rev(xval)),
      y=c(summary, rev(recent)),
      col=colors[[c]]
    )
    recent = summary
  }
}
```

Comment: Suggested tweak: add `...` to the parameter list so all `plot` function parameters are available for use.  In particular, `xaxs="i"` will get rid of white margin between the stacked graph and the edges of the plot.

Answer (score 1):

Simply specify `position = "stack"` within `geom_line(position = "stack")` . For example:

```
dat <- data.frame(x = c(1:5,1:5),
              y = c(9:5, 10,7,5,3,1),
              type = rep(c("a", "b"), each = 5))

library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)


dat %>% 
  ggplot(aes(fill = type,
             x = x,
             y = y,
         color = type,
         linetype = type)) +
  geom_line(position = "stack", size = 2) + # specify it here
  theme_bw()
```

leads to stacked line plot:

[image]

Or, you can also combine stacked line plot with `geom_area` plot [as shown here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63599077/r-ggplot2-geom-area-get-linetype-by-group/63599188#63599188):

```
    dat %>% 
  ggplot(aes(fill = type,
             x = x,
             y = y,
         color = type,
         linetype = type)) +
  geom_area(position="stack", 
            stat="identity",
            alpha = 0.5) +
  geom_line(position = "stack", size = 2) + 
  theme_bw()
```

[image]