# Unable to get a correctly stacked line graph in R

Tags: r, ggplot2, data-visualization

I am using the first answer in [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13644529/how-to-create-a-stacked-line-plot) to create a stacked line graph, but I see some anomalies in the resulting graph. The distribution of two words over different editions of a journal is as follows:

[image]

I don't understand why the white space appears below the lowest stack. If for example, I visualize only the distribution of "political" the line touches the x axis when it becomes 0 (as it should). In case of the stacked bar chart, it simply, and incorrectly floats over the x axis.

[image]

Edit: `head(df)` gives the following output:

```
     year_ed     word total_freq editions
8    2010_1 political        170        1
12   2010_1     media        165        1
26   2010_2     media         23        2
29   2010_2 political          0        2
37   2010_3     media        137        3
39   2010_3 political        131        3
47   2010_4     media         75        4
```

The line of code to plot the stacked graph (for both words) is

```
ggplot(df, aes(x = editions, y = total_freq, fill = word)) + geom_area(position = 'stack')
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: added data and code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe that this is a result of **ggplot**'s behavior when `stat = "identity"`, which is the default for `geom_area`. I can't recall what it used to do with `geom_area`, but now the order of the rows in the data frame impact how things are stacked (when `stat = "identity"`!).

Try the following:

```
df <- read.table(text = "     year_ed     word total_freq editions
8    2010_1 political        170        1
12   2010_1     media        165        1
26   2010_2     media         23        2
29   2010_2 political          0        2
37   2010_3     media        137        3
39   2010_3 political        131        3
47   2010_4     media         75        4",header = TRUE,sep = "")

library(dplyr)

df <- arrange(df,editions,word)
ggplot(df, aes(x = editions, y = total_freq, fill = word)) + 
    geom_area(position = 'stack')
```

[image]

```
df <- arrange(df,editions,desc(word))
ggplot(df, aes(x = editions, y = total_freq, fill = word)) + 
    geom_area(position = 'stack')
```

[image]

If the ordering of the `word` variable is inconsistent within the data frame, I think you'll see inconsistent stacking.