# R ggplot2: geom_area get linetype by group

Tags: r, dplyr

I am trying to differentiate the linetype and/or color in stacked `geom_area` by group. How can I do that? Simply `geom_area(linetype = type)` or `color = type` does not work. Only think that works changes the values for both groups: `geom_area(color = "white")`. How can I modify the color and linetype by group?

My dummy example:

```
dat <- data.frame(x = c(1:5,1:5),
              y = c(9:5, 10,7,5,3,1),
              type = rep(c("a", "b"), each = 5))
```

[image]

My `geom_area`:

```
library(dplyr)

dat %>% 
  ggplot(aes(fill = type,
            x = x,
            y = y)) +
 geom_area(position="stack", 
          stat="identity",
          alpha = 0.5,
          color = "white")
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add some extra aesthetics and a `geom_line()`

```
dat %>% 
  ggplot(aes(fill = type,
             x = x,
             y = y,
         color = type,
         linetype = type)) +
  geom_area(position="stack", 
            stat="identity",
            alpha = 0.5) +
  geom_line(position = "stack", size = 2)
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest this approach. You can work around `aes()` to define the color using a variable (`type`) and then you can apply same method for `aes()` in `geom_area()` to define linetype. I added a large size so that the difference can be seen:

```
#Data
dat <- data.frame(x = c(1:5,1:5),
                  y = c(9:5, 10,7,5,3,1),
                  type = rep(c("a", "b"), each = 5))

library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)
#Plot
dat %>% 
  ggplot(aes(fill = type,
             x = x,
             y = y,color=type)) +
  geom_area(position="stack", 
            stat="identity",
            alpha = 0.5,aes(linetype=type),size=3)
```

Output:

[image]